# How to add a class via jQuery where the class has no name

Tags: jquery, selector, addclass

In jQuery, how do I select and add a class to a class when the class does not have a value?

Here is some example code:

```
<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <span class=""><i class=""></i></span>
    <div class="">
      <span class=""></span>
      <span class=""></span>
    </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
  </div><!-- /.info-box -->
</div>
```

If I only have the above code, how can I achieve the following code by using jQuery:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="info-box">
    <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
    <div class="info-box-content">
      <span class="info-box-text">Messages</span>
      <span class="info-box-number">1,410</span>
    </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
  </div><!-- /.info-box -->
</div>
```

I know that jQuery has the addClass() function, yet I am not sure how to use this when the class I wish to add to does not have a class value.

Is there a specific jQuery technique that I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any control over your HTML code? `addClass` is really meant for manipulating the class of an HTML element. jQuery works on css-like selectors, so typically you would add a way to identify elements in your HTML code (such as add class attributes), and then manipulate those elements via jQuery or javascript...

Comment: Are you asking how to add a class to an element without a class or ID to select it by?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to select an element and give it a class. Take a look here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Using a template engine is something you might consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add IDs to your elements?

Then you can do $('#element').addClass('info-box') etc

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("div[class='']").each(function(i){
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                $(this).addClass("col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12");
                break;
            case 1:
                $(this).addClass("info-box");
                break;
            case 2:
                $(this).addClass("info-box-content");
                break;
            default:
                $(this).addClass("yawn");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

This is how you call the non-value class of an element in jquery.

```
$("div[class='']").addClass("test");
```

or at least, that's how i can come up with.

> http://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/4keypu23/1/

Comment: What is making the `test` class emphasized?

Comment: @MikeiLL I had edited the post, and I didn't emphasize it since the question is just how to select the no-value class element in jquery. Just add your own class if you want to emphasize it.

Comment: Right - i realize it's just the "icon" that looks different.

Comment: That's awesome, man. In your switch function, are you basically counting the DOM elements as they occur in the page? I made a fork of your fiddle which is a little ore colorful and adds span declarations: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/4keypu23/1/

Comment: @MikeiLL Lol, I think so too. I'll just post your fiddle instead of my ugly one.